# Search all sub registry keys for JavaSoft and then delete all of its findings

Tags: powershell, registry

Hi guys I need to write a powershell code that would search all sub registry keys of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE for JavaSoft then delete all of its findings.

Eg from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_SWV_LAYER_22\HU\S-1-5-21-2326696884-2449089384-3618183816-500\Software\JavaSoft

or

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_SWV_LAYER_22\HU\S-1-5-21-602162358-1897051121-1417001333-233697\Software\JavaSoft

but the number will be always different. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wild card `*` like this:

```
Get-Item HKLM:\_SWV_LAYER_22\HU\*\Software\JavaSoft
```

Note - you can use multiple wild cards.

If you still need to recurse you can use this:

```
dir -recurse -Path HKLM:\_SWV_LAYER_22\HU | ? {$_.Name -eq "JavaSoft"}
```